# OAuth: Why should I create an application on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

To authenticate a user on my web application with the user's Facebook profile using OAuth, an application needs to be created on Facebook. Why is this application necessary and does it have any role beyond using it for authentication? Because my web application is not related to Facebook or does not reduce within the Facebook ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to create an App for authenticating a user with his Facebook profile. Autentication means "authorizing an App to get information about the Facebook user". It's not a "Facebook Login", it's an "App Login".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: so if create WebApp1 and WebApp2 separate applications that both rely on Facebook OAuth, is it good practice to use the same App on Facebook to facilitate OAuth based authentication? In other words, is there any stipulation that for each external application, there must be an unique Facebook app?

Comment: @WebUser: You can not use the same FB app for login across different domains (different subdomains work, and using some “workarounds” you can use maybe a handful of different domains with just one app – but you rather shouldn’t). If you have different web apps with different functionality and/or different user bases, then you should use different FB apps for login to those as well.

Comment: @CBroe the way I acknowledged (not understood) the concept of OAuth was that it was a REST based interface to authenticate using a (social) profile. So as I started to explore it and found out that I have to create an App in Facebook, I was surprised because I didn't quite see how an App in Facebook would be related to my external application. So the only thing the Facebook "Login App" does is facilitate authentication to a unique, external application?

Comment: you will understand better if you just test it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.4

Comment: @WebUser: But you are not the only developer using Facebook for login to their apps – and somehow my login to _your_ web app must be distinguished from my login to _that-other-guy’s-web-app_, right? (Especially when permissions come into play – that I granted that other app the permission to undertake action _foo_ via the FB API in my name, does not mean that I want to grant _your_ app – and all other apps out there – that same permission.)